# How to make SignalR E2E tests faster

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, signalr, e2e-testing, signalr.client

I'm E2E testing my ASP.NET Web Api project with `WebApplicationFactory<Program>`, and, for "normal" http endpoints (Controllers), it's pretty fast, as it should be, since it's all in the same computer.

However, now I've to include some tests for a SignalR hub in there.

After googling a bit, this was the approach I used:

```cs
var hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
    .WithUrl(_factory.Server.BaseAddress + "hub",  options =>
    {
        options.AccessTokenProvider = () => Task.FromResult(responseDict?["token"]);
        options.HttpMessageHandlerFactory = _ => _factory.Server.CreateHandler();
    })
    .AddJsonProtocol(options =>
    {
        options.PayloadSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter());
    })
    .Build();


await hubConnection.StartAsync();
```

However, I've noticed that this is very slow, like hubConnection.StartAsync() takes about 4 seconds to reach my OnConnectedAsync method on the hub.

Is there someway to make it faster? Maybe this approach that I've taken of using a HttpMessageHandlerFactory has some unnecessary overhead?

Comment: if anyone comes looking at this, I've managed to make it a lot faster by specifying the Transports for it with:

`options.Transports = HttpTransportType.ServerSentEvents;`

I guess that it was wasting time trying to negotiate between long polling, server sent events, and web sockets, and by just specifying one it became a lot faster, now it's basically instantly

(I couldn't get it to work with websockets, but server side events is fast enough)